# multiple submit buttons in one form in html/php

Tags: html, forms, button, save, submit

I have a form as shown below in which I have multiple save button as shown below.

```
<form method="post" style="display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;text-align: left;">
   <input type="hidden" id="savechanges" name="savechanges" value="1">
   <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td valign="top">
               <!-- Content 1 START -->
               <fieldset style="background-color:darkseagreen;">                         
                  <div>
                     <button type="submit">Save</button>    <!-- Line A -->
                  </div>
               </fieldset>
               <!-- Content 1 END -->   

                 <!-- Content 2 START -->
               <fieldset style="background-color:darkseagreen;">
                  <div>
                     <button type="submit">Save</button>    <!-- Line B -->                       
                  </div>
               </fieldset>
               <!-- Content 2 END -->   
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</form>
```

**Problem Statement:**

The issue which I am having right now is there are two save buttons at **Line A** and **Line B**.

On hitting save button at **Line A**, it saves the entire content in the **1st fieldset** and the **2nd fieldset**. The same thing is happening in the **2nd fieldset**. On 
hitting save button at **Line B**, it saves the entire content in the **1st fieldset** and the **2nd fieldset**.

I am wondering what changes I should make in the code above so that when I hit the save button at **Line A**, it should only save the content in the **1st fieldset** and same thing with other save button at Line B. When I hit the save button at **Line B**, it should save the content in the **2nd fieldset**.

Comment: Use `ajax` for that i.e : `onclick` of submit button ,save that via `ajax` and `js`.

Answer (score 0):

You should make 2 different forms with each fieldset.

Comment: Yes. Or you can also write a JavaScript handler for each button, but it's more complicated.

Comment: Thats the final changes I did in my codebase. I have created the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5tm2g3dp/1/ as well.